# How can I eliminate sonar qube issue when calling the run method of FutureTask?

Tags: java, multithreading, sonarqube, futuretask

I have the below code for which Sonar Qube is raising a critical error.

```
public void onMessageReceived(Message message) {

    if((message.getTargetInstanceId() != Message.ANY_TARGET) && (message.getTargetInstanceId() != this.instanceId)) {
        //Invalid message ignore
        return;
    } else {
        int randTime = ran.nextInt(2000);
        FutureTask<Message> workerTask = new FutureTask<>(new DummyCommandHandler(randTime, message,messageBus,instanceId)); 
        workerTask.run();
    }


}
```

Below is the issue I am getting.

```
Description Assignee    Resource    New issue
Thread.run() and Runnable.run() should not be called directly : Call the method Thread.start() to execute the content of the run() method in a dedicated thread.
```

To call a start method in FutureTask, it doesn't have a start method in the first place. It only has a run method. How can I overcome this issue? Are there any Java solutions or Sonarqube solutions? Please advice.

Comment: You should probably look into an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SonarQube is right, you should not directly call `futureTask.run()`. Use an ExecutorService instead:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.execute(futureTask1);
```

[This](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html) is a short and good tutorial on the topic.